# How to code a method in Java that accepts one generic argument that could be: one type, a second type or both types? (see example)

Tags: java, generics

Basically I would like a method like:

```
public <E extends BarListener | FooListener> void addListener(E listener) {

}
```

Is it possible without using an ugly `Object` as the argument?

Comment: Not really, but how would `E` be better than `Object`? Do they share a common interface? If you're just trying to limit the acceptable types, how about making this private and create explicit overloads for each type?

Comment: Stop asking the same question over and over. It sounds like you want to add a single [`Decorator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#What_solution_does_it_describe?) listener, and allow it to delegate to member `BarListener` and/or `FooListener` instances.

Comment: @shmosel What you are suggesting does not work :( I would need three overloads: one for BarListener, one for FooListener and a third one for BarListener & FooListener. I don't think the compile allows that due to erasure.

Comment: @RichardBrason You misunderstood: `public void addListener(BarListener listener)` and `public void addListener(FooListener listener)`, both of which call `private void addListenerInternal(Object listener)`.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry but that does not work either. The method call becomes ambiguous. It does not fall back to Object :(

Comment: @RichardBrason How can it be ambiguous when the `Object` version has a different name? (addListener**Internal**)